# Codenameone android build error manifest merger

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, codenameone

I have been using the default codescanner cn1-lib but I got sick of the app having to download and external app to scan qr codes on android. So I downloaded the littlemonkey zbar cn1-lib and I added both .cn1lib files to my lib directory and then I started getting build errors. The first were about the minSdkVersion couldn't be lower than a library's sdk version so I changed the build hint `android.min_sdkversion=15` then I started getting the error that the java version of the main project can't be lower than a library so I changed build.xml all 'target' and 'source' to 1.8 and I added the build hint `java.version=8` however I am still getting a build error. 
The log is giving me a `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

```
    Merging result:ERROR
/tmp/build5026335701129669511xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:43:149-325 Warning:
    Element activity#com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity at AndroidManifest.xml:43:149-325 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:43:3-149
/tmp/build5026335701129669511xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:43:114-146 Error:
    Attribute activity#com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:43:114-146
    is also present at [:ZBarScannerLibrary:] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-36 value=(Scanner).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:43:3-149 to override.
```

I paste binned the whole log: https://pastebin.com/tBJJvGkR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do, what exactly Manifest merger suggests you?

> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:43:3-149 to override.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s `<activity>` element add `tools:replace="android:label"`.

Answer (score 2):

You should update to the latest QR scanner library using the Extensions section of Codename One Settings.  It should resolve that issue.